# Solve the following system of equations - (3)

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

> Solve the following system of equations:
>   $$\large
> \left\{
> \begin{align*}
> 3x^2 + xy - 4x + 2y - 2 = 0\\
> x(x + 1) + y(y + 1) = 4
> \end{align*}
> \right.
> $$

I tried writing the first equation as $(x - 2)(3x + y - 10) = -18$, but it didn't help.

Comment: Only for $$y\ne 2$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner For $x\neq 2$, yes. Then we can say if $x=2$, $y$ must equal $14/6$ and this does not satisfy the second equation.

Comment: But you forgot this to say.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Good thing 4 other people already have answers. (Since OP updated the question, now $y=\frac{2+4x-3x^2}{2+x}$. For $x\neq -2$, of course.)

Comment: Well.... uh.... (I'm sorry.)

Comment: Is this corrected now?

Comment: Yup. You can be sure of that.

Comment: I am surprised that each answer provided a different value at least for $y$!!!

Comment: Someone *cough* typed the question wrong. *cough cough*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solving the first equation for $y$ we get $$y=\frac{-3x^2+4x+2}{2+x}$$ for $$x\neq -2$$
plugging this in the second equation we get after simplifications
$$(5x+4)(x-1)^3=0$$

Comment: Please wait. I typed the problem wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Substituting for the updated equation yields
$$
x=-\frac{4}{5}, \; y=-\frac{13}{5}
$$
or $(x,y)=(1,1)$. This is a very pleasant result, compared with the old one (with $-xy$ in the first equation instead of $xy$).

$$
x=\frac{5y^3 - 26y^2 - 24y + 91}{65},
$$
with 
$$
5y^4 + 9y^3 - 11y^2 - 12y - 13=0.
$$

Comment: I apologize. I typed the question wrong.

Comment: @LêThànhĐạt And what is the correct question?

Comment: I just fixed it. Thanks for asking.

Comment: @LêThànhĐạt I fixed my answer, too.

Comment: It is not clear how the equation of degree 4 in y was reached...

Comment: @NoChance It came from a typo in the first equation, namely $-xy$ instead of $+xy$.

Comment: Thanks for clarification however, still it is not clear how did you get $x=5y^3-26y^2....$

Answer (score 0):

The resultant of $3\,{x}^{2}-xy-4\,x+2\,y-2$ and $
x \left( x+1 \right) +y \left( y+1 \right) -4$ with respect to $y$ is
$$ 10\,{x}^{4}-24\,{x}^{3}-10\,{x}^{2}+42\,x-8$$
which is irreducible over the rationals.  Its roots can be written in terms of
radicals, but they are far from pleasant.  There are two real roots, 
$x \approx -1.287147510$ and  $x \approx 0.2049816008$, which correspond to 
$y \approx -2.469872787$ and $y \approx 1.500750095$ respectively.

EDIT: For the corrected question, the resultant of $3\,{x}^{2}+xy-4\,x+2\,y-2$ and $x \left( x+1 \right) +y \left( y+1 \right) -4$ with respect to $y$ is
$$ 10 x^4 - 22 x^3 + 6 x^2 + 14 x - 8 = 2 (5 x + 4) (x-1)^3$$
Thus we want $x = -4/5$, corresponding to $y = -13/5$, or $x = 1$, corresponding to $y = 1$.

Comment: Could you wait for me a little bit? I typed the problem wrong.